# How to make anchors of iframe to be opened in the parent window

Tags: iframe, scroll, header, height, anchor

### I AM TRYING TO

To open the link in the same parent page, instead of open it in a new page.

#### Note

The iframe and parent page are the same domain.

#### Code for iframe

```
<div id="phase"> <iframe src="worksheader.html"  name="myiFrame" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"  height="100%" width="100%"></iframe> <iframee src="http://www.ahmadalanazi.com"  name="myiFrame" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"  height="100%" width="100%"></iframe> </div>
```

#### Code for the hyperlink element

```
<a target="_parent" href="#my-id">Jump to anchor/a>
```

#### [EXAMPLE HERE](http://www.ahmadalanazi.com/pleasehelp)

Comment: There is no example code posted in your question. You may try asking here as well: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please guys. I am stuck in this !! Its a life changing thing.

Answer (score 0):

Your description makes it slightly hard to understand what you are trying to accomplish, but if you are trying to achieve *smooth scrolling*, then this link will help you:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

You will need jQuery for this.